# Editing all faces of a cube with one plane (with identical copies of the plane)

Tags: modeling

I've over complicated it with background. I just want to edit one side (or face) of a cube (or a proxy side of that cube) and Blender to automatically edit all of it's sides in the same way, with a mirror modifier applied to each side, mirroring on each individual side's normal orientations of those sides, with a subdivision surface modifier applied to the whole object, on top of that. However, something that does the same job is good too, as long as it allows for real time previews of the outcome.

This is what I'm looking for:

The mirror modifier applies to only one side of the currently unmade cube.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The mirror modifier is applied and copies of that side are joined together to form the cube.[![enter image description here][2]][2]

The subdivision surface modifier is applied to the completed cube after doubles are removed.
(Not enough reputation, of which 10 is required, to post more than two links, such as images. Sorry.)

The thing is, though, that whole process is automated and happens within a tenth of a second after the base mesh (the original side) is edited and is repeated as it continues to be edited (with the necessary cleanup of objects, etc.).

Maybe programming for task automation is the solution, but I would have thought Blender would have a way of doing this without programming. (I came to Blender from Python programming, so it's no big deal to me if it requires Python programming).

Comment: It would be much easier to answer questions like this if some screenshots of the objects along with Properties editor opened and if necessary some other important options are provided. There could be many ways to interpret this question as for now.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the good advice. How do I add screenshots to my posts? Also, how do I add GIFs? I'm guessing there's an option somewhere, but you know the internet when it comes to interfaces. Maybe I shouldn't be so hasty. I'm always research first, figure out later. I'll mess around with the options I have.

Comment: See [meta post](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/add-images-to-stack-exchange-questions) about adding images (basically it means to put cursor in the text field and press Ctrl+G), about gifs see [here](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers). Please note also that images etc should add description to the text, not substitute it.

Comment: The images are not showing correctly.

Comment: Hi. I had seen this, but didn't have time to reply because I had to rush to go to an HSP meeting. I can reply now, though, so here goes. :) The images don't work, but I don't know how to make them work. Please can you help me see what I did wrong?

Comment: The images worked at first, but now they've stopped working. It's probably a silly mistake I made. I get that all the time with Python programming. Thank you for any help. :)