# How do I apply three array modifiers to only one plane and have that plane be the same, editable, plane

Tags: modeling

This was basically the same as other questions I've asked, except it specifies the array modifier, as modifiers allows for control over the stages which other modifiers are used on an object. I'm changing the question, in the hopes of finding the solution I'm looking for. I'm as sorry as I can make myself feel, as a sociopath (a victim of sociopath characteristics), that I duplicated questions. I did it because I thought each question might be more specific or cover a slightly different area. Now that I've thought about it, I realise I can just edit the same question next time. Again, I'm sorry. If I could be, I'd be very sorry. My problem would be completely solved if I just learned how to do one more thing and that is use three array modifiers on the same stage of the mesh, so that all three array modifiers are arraying only 1 plane, instead of the first one arraying one plane, the second one arraying 4 planes and the third one arraying 1 plane. Is there an inbuilt feature or Python code or a plugin or a mod that does this? Also, if you know of a better way of finding out this information, please let me know. Thank you very much for any help. :)

Comment: You'll need 2 array modifiers and 2 empty objects to control their rotation but I don't know how you would avoid the double opposite face as the merge function only works on the current modifier.

Comment: You have made like three questions exactly like this in the past few days here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64963/how-do-i-mirror-the-faces-of-a-cube-edit-all-of-them-when-i-edit-one here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65100/how-do-i-use-the-array-modifier-to-make-an-editable-cube-from-a-plane and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65006/editing-all-faces-of-a-cube-with-one-plane-with-identical-copies-of-the-plane Please don't spam the site and add more details to your questions if you expect to get quality answers

Comment: Consider reviewing the answers provided there and mark them as correct if they solved your problem, or at least upvote them if they helped. If they didn't then explain why so a better answer can be provided

Comment: Making a symmetrical cube, is it an option to you  to model the corner of a cube and use mirror modifier with all the XYZ axes? But its kind of opposite of what you asked. Maybe you make 2 objects using the same mesh and boolean them together?